Adding extra cost to woocommerce flat rate based on shipping zone
i found solution to count flat rate based on specific quantity steps in woocommerce, what i need additionally to add an extra specific amount based on shipping zone. for example : i charged customer 4 dollar for each 3 items based on specific shipping class, so if the customer added 6 items to cart with the same shipping class he will charged 8 dollar, what i need then to add 50 dollar additional based on the customer shipping zone so the total shipping cost get 58 dollar (8 for items number + 50 for shipping zone), also i want to be abble to add many shipping classes and many shipping zones to the code.
Here is the code :
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'progressive_shipping_cost_based_shipping_class_quantity_steps', 10, 2 );
function progressive_shipping_cost_based_shipping_class_quantity_steps( $rates, $package )
{
    // HERE Bellow your settings
    $shipping_class = "very-light-weight"; // The shipping class ID
    $qty_step       = 20; // Items qty threshold for a step
    $item_count     = 0; // Initializing

    // Get the shipping class ID
    $class_id = get_term_by('slug', $shipping_class, 'product_shipping_class' )->term_id;


    // Loop through in cart items to get the Tshirts count
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
        if ( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class_id ){
            $item_count += $cart_item['quantity']; // Count Tshirts
        }
    }

    // The rate operand increase each {$qty_step} depending on {$item_count}
    $rate_operand = ceil( $item_count / $qty_step );

    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // Targetting "Flat rate"
        if( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $has_taxes = false;

            // Set the new cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rate->cost * $rate_operand;

            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $tax > 0 ){
                    // New tax calculated cost
                    $taxes[$key] = $tax * $rate_operand;
                    $has_taxes = true;
                }
            }
            // Set new taxes cost
            if( $has_taxes )
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}

i trired the followong code to add extra 50 dollar to shipping rate but it doesn't work :
// Add $50 shipping cost based on shipping zone
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'add_custom_shipping_rate', 10, 2);
function add_custom_shipping_rate($rates, $package) {
    $zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_matching_package($package);
    $zone_name = $zone->get_zone_name();
    
    if ($zone_name === 'Your Shipping Zone Name') {
        foreach ($rates as $rate_key => $rate) {
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost += 50;
        }
    }
    
    return $rates;
}



Try the following code to increase the shipping cost based on the shipping zone. You can add as many shipping zones and increment costs in the given code.
function add_custom_shipping_rate( $rates, $package ) {
    // Shipping zone
    $shipping_zone = wc_get_shipping_zone( $package );
    
    // Get zone ID
    $zone_id = $shipping_zone->get_id();

    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        if($zone_id == 1){
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rate->cost + 40;
        }
        else if($zone_id == 2){
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rate->cost + 50;
        }
        else{
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rate->cost;
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'add_custom_shipping_rate', 10, 2 );

The code has been tested and works.

Thank you very much, it works very well
i just want to apply the same conditional concept to quantity steps to be abble to add as many shipping class and quantiy steps
for example :
if shipping_class = "very-light-weight"
qty_step       = 20;
if shipping_class = "heavy-weight"
qty_step       = 10;
